# Task scheduler compatibility?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, compatibility, windows-task-scheduler

With what windows versions is a task exported in XML compatible with? For example, is a task created in windows 7 compatible with windows 10 / Windows Server 2003 with Windows Server 2008 and so on? I know there are a lot of different options here, I am specifically interested in compatibility between windows 7, 8 and 10 but if you have more information please share!

Also what does the "Configure For" option really do when making a task?

Comment: Look here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749579(v=ws.11).aspx ... It appears that the Win 7, 8, and 10 are compatible and the "configure for" option per this post https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851678(v=ws.11).aspx `you can restrict the options displayed to those that are also available in previous operating systems`... this means that the configure for should be set to the OS which the task is defined to see options that may not have been there with other OSes but those appear to be compatible regardless and the XML import/export should work

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this link:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851678(v=ws.11).aspx

> For computers that are running Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 7,
>   Windows Server 2008, or Windows Vista, you can restrict the options
>   displayed to those that are also available in previous operating
>   systems. **Doing this does not configure the task or the preference
>   item to run on earlier operating systems.**

This means you have forward compatibility being able to use the task but no guarantee for backward compatibility. It also means that you will be able to see only the options relevant to the specified OS in the "Configure for" selection.